# Does a cell suspend or exit cell cycle at G0?

Tags: cell-biology, terminology, cell-division, cell-cycle

In an exam, there was one question which asked whether the cell **exits** or **suspends** cell cycle at G0 phase.

I answered that it exits cell cycle but the official answer key says it suspends cell cycle.

I marked exit because a cell in G0  undergoes differentiation and maturation. Is there a difference between the two terms?

Comment: The answer is exit. I had given this exam this year and marked the same answer as yours and its correct.

Comment: and also if you wanna know the difference between the two words , a similar terminology has already been answered on SE. Visit - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265911/what-are-the-differences-between-kill-suspend-and-terminate-of-a-process

Comment: I've always heard of it referred to as exiting and re-entering the cell cycle. Of course some cells do not re-enter. This seems to be a matter of semantics. I don't think it's prudent or even sensible to make an exam question based on what verb to use to refer to the process of delaying or avoiding entry into the G1 phase of the cell cycle. [Mandatory reading.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:How_many_legs_does_a_horse_have%3F)

Answer (score 1):

It is actually suspend and yes the words do differ. This is because the cells that enter the G0 stage is not actually exiting the cell cycle because when situation demands it will divide. It is metabolically active and therefore the word suspend suits better

Comment: Please add some references so this doesn't get downvoted :)